# String in javascript function argument returns "Unexpected end of input"

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have ajax request function

```
 function Reject(id, scomment)
  {
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "reject.php",
       data: {id: id, Scomment: scomment},
       cache: false,
       success: function(response)
       {
        location.reload();
       }
     });
 }
```

There is html from my php loop

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<textarea id="Scomment" name="Scomment" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="Reject('.$row['id'].', "sample text");">Reject</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

So..

If i will use string.

```
onClick="Reject('.$row['id'].', "sample text");"
```

console returns Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

But..
If i will use any number instead of "sample text"

```
onClick="Reject('.$row['id'].', 262434);"
```

It works.

I am newbie and kindly please support me guys.

Comment: Watch your quotes. Try `onClick="Reject('.$row['id'].', 'sample text');"`

Comment: just escape the `"` signs

Comment: But how, its php with html codes

Comment: onClick="Reject(`.$row['id'].`, 'sample text');"    use this, I have used backtick to avoid confusion in first parameter.

Comment: There is no need for JavaScript for what you're doing here.  All you need is a simple form.  The button clicked as the submit button is sent in the POST data, which you can access server-side.  You're making this much harder on yourself and reducing compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to escape your double quotation, this error happens because the starting and ending quote will not match with the current implementation.

Like this:

```js
onClick="Reject('.$row['id'].', \"sample text\");"
```

Or use single quote instead.

```js
onClick="Reject('.$row['id'].', 'sample text');"
```

Comment: Dear, If i want to use document.getElementById("Scomment").value instead of sample text. How to do?

Comment: @ლევანსაყვარელიძე This is exactly the same as before, you can do it like this: `document.getElementById(\"Scomment\")` or `document.getElementById('Scomment')`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quotes in double quotes. This leads to problem.

You can use single quotes in double quotes and viceversa like this

```
onClick="Reject('.$row['id'].', 'sample text');"
```